# Div isn't in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with several divs inside it. These divs in the div aren't in div, but height is working.
Here's the page ruler's screen and page screen

[image]

```css
.navbar {
  width: 97%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.2%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
.navbar .item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  background: linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 0.75%;
  padding-right: 0.75%;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <h1>yourword</h1>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="item left">Home</div>
  <div class="item left">About</div>
  <div class="item right">Action</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Its SCSS**, i will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the classes `left` and `right` declare the `float` value to be left and right.

You need to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.navbar`. This will create a block formatting context, and `navbar` will now have it's height affected by the floated elements.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this:

**CSS**

```
.navbar{
  width:97%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top:0.2%;
  padding-bottom:0.2%;
  display: block;
  border:none;
}
.navbar > .item{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:0.5%;
    padding-bottom:0.5%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
    background: linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
    border:1px solid #d5d5d5;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    padding-left:0.75%;
    padding-right:0.75%;
    height:inherit;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

```css
.navbar {
  width: 97%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.2%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
.navbar > .item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  background: linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 0.75%;
  padding-right: 0.75%;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>yourword</h1>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="item left">Home</div>
  <div class="item left">About</div>
  <div class="item right">Action</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to write out `.item` as a descendant of `.navbar` since you can't nest css inside of each other in that manner.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 97%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.2%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
.navbar .item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  background: linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 50%, #eee);
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 0.75%;
  padding-right: 0.75%;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>yourword</h1>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="item left">Home</div>
  <div class="item left">About</div>
  <div class="item right">Action</div>
</div>
```